# How should "Have you ever been issued a passport or ID for travel by any other country" be answered by previous green card holders?

Tags: usa, esta

My Mom had a green card which expired in 2011. She didn't formally relinquish her status, and she has not been in the US since then. We want to apply for an ESTA for her and we're not sure what to answer "Have you ever been issued a passport or ID for travel by any other country" with since technically a green card is a travel document issued by another country. Should we put that information here and answer YES?

Comment: More information is always better than omission. But did your mom formally relinquish her status as a permanent resident of the United States? If not, she may still be a U.S. LPR and can encounter issues. Expiry of green card is irrelevant to if one is still a permanent resident.

Comment: She had not been in the US in the last 11 years so technically she abandoned her status.

Comment: It is almost certain she will be considered to have abandoned such status when examined by a border officer or immigration judge. But until then, she can still be treated as an LPR (even though at the border she is likely to be asked to relinquish the status formally) and be ineligible for ESTA. An I-407 could be filed outside the U.S. and clarify the status.

Comment: @DIANA what did you and your mother end up doing in this case?